# Update a table column using a subquery from the same table (Moving Average)

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table containing stockmarket data (High Low, Open, Close), I have calculated the moving average using a widely used query

```
SELECT PriceID, CompanyID, Ticker, Timestamp, [Open], High, Low, [Close], Volume, 
AVG([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY PriceID ASC ROWS 9 PRECEDING) AS Ten_MovAvg
FROM Prices
```

The Prices table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Prices] (
  [PriceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [CompanyID] [int] NULL,
  [Ticker] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
  [Open] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
  [High] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
  [Low] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
  [Close] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
  [Volume] [int] NOT NULL,
  [MovAvg] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
```

I want the moving average to update the MovAvg column.  I believe you cannot select and update the same table at the same time.  I have used a view to collate the data successfully, but the client side performance is very slow with this solution (using Entity Framework and a C# WinForm).

Is there a way to use a temporary table and pass the data back to the original table or is there a better solution?  Ultimately I need the data in a  in the application.  I want the processing of the Moving average to completed in a one off, as the data is fairly static and only changes daily (i.e. I don't want the calculation to be performed multiple times during usage as the process is quite slow).

Comment: Sample data and expected results and the DDL/DML statements to create sample data would improve your question.

Comment: Storing a computed value is always prone to issues, it might be possible to get your query working effectively. Otherwise use a stored procedure to update and select.

Comment: Thanks Dale - the stored procedure was the way to go for me.  I made a new table that was passed the calculated values.